# Add Max-age to Big Commerce CDN Images

Tags: performance, browser-cache, bigcommerce, webpagetest, max-age

I am currently running performance testing on my sites, all of which are hosted through Big Commerce (cornerstone theme, stencil). I am using webpagetest.org, and under the performance section, there is a metric "Leverage browser caching of static assets". There they have listed many images all that are hosted through Big Commerce's CDN, that have failed for no max-age or because they have expired.
I spoke to a big commerce rep and I understand that all the images are cached, but is there a way to add a max-age to the cache? not sure what else to do, so any suggestions would be appreciated!

side note- I know my images are well optimized, but the cache score is the specific issue, webpagetest.org gives the cache a 52/100 score...

Answer (score -1):

big commerce is becoming more late of the art the more we stay with this company

Comment: Jacob Scott, this does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)